# Print non-ascii text in Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I have a dictionary of Facebook group names and group id  retreived from Facebook using graph API .

When I simply Print it using

```
for i in name:
  print i['name']
```

It prints all the group names even the ones in other languages such as Arabic and French.

but for this statement

```
check=raw_input("Want to post in %s?(Y/N)" % i['name'])
```

Group names with the non English Characters are not being printed.
Why is this happening?

Comment: @Puciek Now it prints it but in the unicode form like \u5411\u464\564.How to get the charecters

Comment: What operating system? What is `sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: @LennartRegebro ubuntu 13.04

Comment: What is `repr(i['name'])`? What is sys.getdefaultencoding()?

Comment: sys.getdefaultconfig() gives 'ascii' and print repr(i['name']) gives all the names but  like u'\u5411\u464\u564'

Comment: also type(i['name']) returns unicode

Comment: OK, got it, updated answer. I don't know why you didn't get encode/decode error from the start, but there you go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Want to post in %s?(Y/N)"` is not Unicode.

Prefix it with a `u`:

```
u"Want to post in %s?(Y/N)" % i['name']
```

However, `raw_input()` doesn't like having Unicode text as the prompt. So you need to encode it with the encoding that your standard out uses.

```
prompt = u"Want to post in %s?(Y/N) " % i['name']
check = raw_input(prompt.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

Comment: I got the error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-24: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Stormvirux: Aha. Then the strings in the `i` dictionary is *also* not Unicode, so you are in fact not trying to print Unicode at all.

Comment: @Stormvirux: Absolutely not. You need to read up more about Unicode and encodings. Start here: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/ Then here: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html